Can't connect to SQL Server on my on-premises server using PHP connection
I have been trying to connect to SQL Server which is on-premises. I keep getting the below error message

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'IIIINfsadiq'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'IIIINfsadiq'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'IIIINfsadiq'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'IIIINfsadiq'. ) )

I have installed the necessary drivers based on my PHP version. Though I use IIIIN\fsadiq which is my username (Windows) to log in without a password.
I created a connection script just to see if it will connect to SQL Server. See script below.
<?php

$serverName = "171.11.111.111";
$database = "ISS_CFW";
$uid = "IIIIN\fsadiq";
$pass = "";

$connection = [
"Database" => $database,
"Uid" => $uid,
"PWD" => $pass
];

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connection);
if(!$conn)
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
else
echo'connection established';

?>

Any solution will be appreciated.

You can't login with a windows username and no password... I don't know what the connection string is in PHP but you need something like integrated security and you don't provide any login details as they are picked up from the machine the PHP is running on.

I highly recommend consulting the connection string reference for your environment.

If you need to use Windows authentication then ensure that the PHP process is running under the context of the correct Windows account and then do not specify username and password details in the connection string. When you supply a username and password you're instructing the client to use SQL Login authentication, which is not compatible with Windows authentication.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455700/iis-php-connect-to-mssql-using-windows-authentication

On a side note, "\f" is a form feed character, so your $uid was incorrect.
